# Alternative to breaking a loop in Angular while iterating through an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I have read online that it is impossible to break *ngFor in Angular but was wondering if anyone has an alternative to this? I have been stuck on this for days on end.

I would like to loop a list all animal names for the user and when the user clicks a specific animal name, info appears below the button they have just clicked.

Please see the example below:

```
<div ="container" *ngFor="let animal of (this.animals || [])">

<h5 (click)="getAnimalInfo(animal.animalName)">{{animal.animalName}}</h5>

<ng-container *ngIf="getAnimalInfo(animal.animalName)"> 
<div class="container" *ngFor="let animalInfo of (this.animalInfo || []);">
      <li {{animalInfo.title}}     </li><br>
      <li {{animalInfo.paragraph}}  </li><br>
</div>
</ng-container>

</div>
```

Currently, when I click an animal name item my original list, it will display the details below every single animal name on the list instead of just the one I have clicked on.

How can I fix this so that the loop knows to break when I select one animal name?

N.B I am aware that if i take my second for loop out of the original for loop, this can work, however I want the data to populate directly under the original button and be toggle-able rather than having the info appear at the very bottom of the full list.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to break loop in *ngFor loop but for you requirement i have given the solution below.

First of all i have defined dummy animals array and animalInfo array in ts file. You can replace with your original array.

```
animals = [{ animalName: 'dog' }, { animalName: 'cat' }];
animalInfo = [{ paragraph: 'dog paragraph', title: 'dog' }, { paragraph: 'cat paragraph', title: 'cat' }];
```

then i have declared selectedAnimalInfo which we can use to store the click animal info.

```
selectedAnimalInfo = {};
```

I am expecting animalName parameter in animal array is same as title parameter of animalInfo arrar.
After that your getAnimalInfo method will be look like below.

```
  getAnimalInfo(animalName: string) {
    this.selectedAnimalInfo = {
      [animalName]: this.animalInfo.find((animal) => animal.title === animalName)
    };
  }
```

And at the end html code

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let animal of (this.animals || [])">

  <h5 (click)="getAnimalInfo(animal.animalName)">{{animal.animalName}}</h5>

    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedAnimalInfo[animal.animalName]">
      <div class="container">
         <li> {{selectedAnimalInfo[animal.animalName].title}} </li><br>
         <li> {{selectedAnimalInfo[animal.animalName].paragraph}} </li><br>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

</div>
```

Hope it will full fill you requirement.